# What Package is missing if IPython console doesn't recognize magic commands?

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Pycharm, and I used to install packages from console, I just precede the commandline instricutions with (!). But it is not working anymore. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: It looks you are expecting an ipython console but are using a regular python console. Have you installed ipython for the Python version used in that project?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Got it! Thanks. I installed that and now it shows [2] instead of >>>